# Delete one side of one-to-one relationship and null out its reference from the other side

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, fluent-nhibernate, cascade, one-to-one

I have two entities which can be related, but they can both exist without having each-other as well. In essence they are both 1 to 0..1.

Entity B can have an Entity A created from it - when this is done it establishes a relationship so that Entity B has 1 Entity A.  Like-wise, since it can return to being optional, the user must be able to delete entity A without deleting its parent Entity B.

In the database my Entity A does not have an Entity B foreign key, so deleting Entity B would never be a problem.

Entity B, however, has a nullable field to hold an Entity A foreign Key.  So far I've been able only to get Nhibernate to leave the bad key in the table, or delete the associated row entirely when you delete it's associated Entity A.

Long story short, if I click delete on Entity A, it should null out the reference to it in the Entity B table, should one exist. How can I go about this in Fluent Mapping?